# Javascript cytoscape.js auto layout with fixed nodes

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js, graph-layout

i'm making a graph layout with cytoscape.js. I want some nodes to have fixed positions. So in my current solution i use the cose layout of cytoscape and set postions for these nodes. It works but i have in my layout some node overlapping. I think the cose layout position the nodes regardless of the fixed nodes. Have anyone ideas how i can fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try locking the nodes that should be stationary: http://js.cytoscape.org/#nodes.lock

Comment: i already lock the fixed nodes and let the other nodes layout automatically but i got node overlapping.

Comment: Adjust your layout options

Comment: Which option is helpful for this ?